# How do I change a line in a datagrid that I marked (MVVM Structure)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I can add texts to the `DataGrid` and by clicking the button (edit) I can drag the data from the `DataGrid` back into the text boxes, but my problem is if I change the data after dragging it over, it is not updated in the `Datagrid`.

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="CV_Projekte" Grid.Column="1" Background="White" Visibility="Visible">
    <Label Content="Projektnumber:" Canvas.Left="44" Canvas.Top="84" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Label Content="Name:" Canvas.Left="43" Canvas.Top="113" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"  />
    <Label Content="Unterposition:" Canvas.Left="44" Canvas.Top="146" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"  />
    <Label Content="Describe:" Canvas.Left="44" Canvas.Top="182" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"  />
    <TextBox Canvas.Left="183" Canvas.Top="89" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="120" Text="{Binding   ProjectNumber}" />
    <TextBox Canvas.Left="44" Canvas.Top="216" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="273" Height="155"/>
    <TextBox Canvas.Left="183" Canvas.Top="151" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox Canvas.Left="183" Canvas.Top="118" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="120" Text="{Binding ProjectName}"/>
    <Button Content="Add" Canvas.Left="383" Canvas.Top="167" Width="75" Command="{Binding  StartCommand}" Opacity="0.2"/>
    <Button Content="Edit" Canvas.Left="383" Canvas.Top="201" Width="75"  Opacity="0.2" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}"  />
    <DataGrid Height="575" Canvas.Left="616" Width="303" ItemsSource="{Binding CareList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCare}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Projektnummer}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Projektname" Width="184" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Delete"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid> 
</Canvas>
```

This is the CareViewModel.cs

```
 public class CareViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _ProtjectNumber;
    private string _ProjectName;
   

    private Visibility _TrackingVisibility;
    private Visibility _CarreVisibility;
    private Care _selectedCare;

    public int ProjectNumber 
    {
        get
        {
            return _ProtjectNumber;
        }
        set
        {

            _ProtjectNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProjectNumber));
        }
    }
    public string ProjectName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _ProjectName;
        }
        set
        {
            _ProjectName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProjectName));
        }
    }



    public Visibility TrackingVisibility 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _TrackingVisibility;
        }
        set 
        {
            _TrackingVisibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_TrackingVisibility));
        }
    }


    public Visibility CareVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _CarreVisibility;
        }

        set
        {
            _CarreVisibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CareVisibility));
        }
    }
   
   
    public void TrackingView(RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        TrackingVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        CareVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public void CareView(RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        TrackingVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        CareVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Care> CareList { get; set; }


    public CareViewModel() 
    {
        CareList        = new ObservableCollection<Care>();  //List
        StartCommand    = new OurCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(Setting);
        TrackingCommand = new OurCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(TrackingView);
        CareCommand     = new OurCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(CareView);
        UpdateCommand   = new OurCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(Bearbeitung);

        TrackingVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        CareVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    public ICommand StartCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand TrackingCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand CareCommand { get; set; }

    public ICommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }

    public Care SelectedCare
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCare;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedCare = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCare));
        }
    }
    public void Setting(RoutedEventArgs e)  // Add the Values to Datagrid
    {
        var projects = new Care();
        projects.Projektnummer = _ProtjectNumber;
        projects.Name = _ProjectName;
        ProjectNumber = 0;
        ProjectName = null;
        SelectedCare = projects;
        CareList.Add(projects);
    }
    public void Bearbeitung(RoutedEventArgs e) //Editing the value button
    {
        ProjectNumber = SelectedCare.Projektnummer;
        ProjectName   = SelectedCare.Name;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    { 
        if(PropertyChanged != null) 
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Class Care

```
public class Care
{
    private int _Projektnummer;
    private string _Name;
   

    
    public int Projektnummer 
    {
        get { return _Projektnummer;}
        set { _Projektnummer = value;}
    }
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return _Name;}
        set { _Name = value;}
    }

   
}
```

Thanks to everyone who wants to help me.

Comment: Show the `CareList` item type class and the code that operated with properties. It must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Also you may use [`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `SelectedItem` binding. And you don't need `Canvas` here but `Grid`, and learn something about panels e.g. `StackPanel`, `WrapPanel`, `DockPanel` etc. It will make you safe from absolute `Control` positioning.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and uploaded the ViewModel above.

Comment: Add `Care` class too.

Comment: The Projektnummer is for ProjectNumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created some demo project from source you provided.

- Selection of the row fills TextBoxes automatically
- **Add** Button creates new row and make it able to edit
- **Save** button applies changes in TextBoxes
- **X** button deletes the row

#### 0. MVVM Helpers

I don't know what is `OurCommand` but I'm using almost unchanged [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic).

```csharp
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

It supports command parameters and everything else related to `ICommand`.

To be able not to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in every View Model, I moved the implementation to the base class.

```cs
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

`[CallerMemberName]` is a compiler trick that allows to call `OnPropertyChanged()` without arguments. Compiler will fill it automatically with Caller Member Name :) - Property name.

#### 1. Markup

Use `Grid` and relative positioning of controls. It will help you to make responsive design where layout looks fine for almost any area size.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="1200" Height="600">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:CareViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EditingCare}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="75"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Projektnumber:"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Name:"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Unterposition:"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Describe:"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding EditingCare.ProjectNumber}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding EditingCare.Name}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding EditingCare.Subtitle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding EditingCare.Description}"/>
            <DockPanel Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
                <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}"  />
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding CareList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCare}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding ProjectNumber}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Projektname" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unterposition" Binding="{Binding Subtitle}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="X" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### 2. Data

To fix the initial problem I've implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the `Care` class.

```csharp
public class Care : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _projectNumber;
    private string _name;
    private string _description;
    private string _subtitle;

    public int ProjectNumber
    {
        get => _projectNumber;
        set
        {
            _projectNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Subtitle
    {
        get => _subtitle;
        set
        {
            _subtitle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get => _description;
        set
        {
            _description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public Care() { }

    public Care(Care care)
    {
        ProjectNumber = care.ProjectNumber;
        Name = care.Name;
        Subtitle = care.Subtitle;
        Description = care.Description;
    }
}
```

#### 2. View Model

I played a lot with code and came up with following one.

```csharp
public class CareViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _trackingVisible;
    private bool _careVisible;
    private Care _selectedCare;
    private Care _editingCare;
    private ObservableCollection<Care> _careList;
    private ICommand _addCommand;
    private ICommand _trackingCommand;
    private ICommand _careCommand;
    private ICommand _updateCommand;
    private ICommand _deleteCommand;

    public ObservableCollection<Care> CareList
    {
        get => _careList;
        set
        {
            _careList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool TrackingVisibility
    {
        get => _trackingVisible;
        set
        {
            _trackingVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool CareVisibility
    {
        get => _careVisible;
        set
        {
            _careVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public Care SelectedCare
    {
        get => _selectedCare;
        set
        {
            _selectedCare = value;
            EditingCare = value is Care care ? new Care(care) : value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Care EditingCare
    {
        get => _editingCare;
        set
        {
            _editingCare = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand TrackingCommand => _trackingCommand ?? (_trackingCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        TrackingVisibility = true;
        CareVisibility = false;
    }));

    public ICommand CareCommand => _careCommand ?? (_careCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        TrackingVisibility = false;
        CareVisibility = true;
    }));

    // Add the Values to Datagrid
    public ICommand AddCommand => _addCommand ?? (_addCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        Care newItem = new Care();
        CareList.Add(newItem);
        SelectedCare = newItem;
    }));
    //Editing the value button
    public ICommand UpdateCommand => _updateCommand ?? (_updateCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        int index = CareList.IndexOf(SelectedCare);
        CareList[index] = EditingCare;
        SelectedCare = CareList[index];
    }, parameter => EditingCare != null && SelectedCare != null));

    public ICommand DeleteCommand => _deleteCommand ?? (_deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is Care care)
        {
            CareList.Remove(care);
        }
    }));

    public CareViewModel()
    {
        CareList = new ObservableCollection<Care>();

        TrackingVisibility = true;
        CareVisibility = false;
    }
}
```

#### 3. Visibility

Among other changes pay attention to former `Visibility` properties now they are bool. And to attach it to controls here's converter that is already meintoined in Markup.

MVVM doesn't suggest to use UI-related types in View Model or Model unless you need it for special purpose.

```csharp
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => value is bool v && v ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => null;
}
```

Usage of converter

```xml
<Button Visibility="{Binding TrackingVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

---

[image]

Comment: really nice of you, thank you. I've only just started my training and I learned c # at school, but at school, it's not like a company (= MVVM is brand new to me. Really thx